# mongodb realm sync client on angular project

Tags: angular, mongodb, realm, mongodb-stitch

I configured realm sync at atlas,.
My client side is angular application.
I installed the
npm install realm@beta

When I try to import
import Realm from "realm";

I get below error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:8:10 - error TS2305: Module '"realm"' has no exported member 'Realm'.
```

How to configure sync at client side from realm sync

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the relevant code of your app.component. It could be important how you import the lib. Also have you made sure that the libs folder exists in your projects node_modules?

Comment: import  Realm from 'realm';

realm folder is present in node_modules